# Condensing multi-line windows batch script into one line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to condense the following into a one liner which can be used in the command prompt. I've tried alternating between && and & and | and || with no success, I keep getting

> ... was unexpected at this time.

Is it possible to condense this into one line?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%l in ('wmic computersystem get SystemType^ /format:list') do >nul 2>&1     set "System_%%l" 

if "%System_SystemType%" == "x64-based PC" (
echo 64bit
) else (
echo 32bit
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wmic computersystem get SystemType | find "x64" >nul&& echo 64bit || echo 32bit
```

and with an additional environment variable `SystemType`:

```
wmic computersystem get SystemType | find "x64" >nul&& (echo 64bit&set "SystemType=64bit") || (echo 32bit&set "SystemType=32bit")
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have one question, I kind of need this to output to a variable that I can then call later on in the script, would you be able to assist me with modifying your above example to accommodate that? thank you.